# How to call WCF service or ASMX service from Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating windows phone 8.1 application, I have created Windows Phone 8 application and I know how to call web service from Windows Phone 8, but I am surprised when I update VS 2013 2,I am not getting "Add Service Reference" option, how do I add service in my Windows Phone 8.1 application?

Comment: Right click on reference and see second option

Comment: @DhavalPatel this is not windows phone 8,thank you!!Have you checked windows phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NiteshKothari you should choose Windows Phone Silverlight Application, that is the point!!

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 8.1 XAML applications does not support the System.ServiceModel namespace, and therefore you are not able to right click references in the project and choose Add Service Reference.

Refer more [`here`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/9ab43a4c-499a-4f2e-81e5-c1ab5acbe9bf/wcf-add-service-reference-not-supported-for-windows-phone-81-xaml-applications?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: sajeetharan, even "Add Service Reference" is also not there in options, thanks!!

Comment: @NiteshKothari Thats what i have answered, there is a workaround yo could follow http://blogs.msdn.com/b/myamama/archive/2014/06/24/workaround-to-adding-service-reference-to-windows-phone-8-1-runtime-app.aspx